# Django Multiple User profiles (design decision)

Tags: django, django-models

The title might seem very familiar (lots of related questions but I couldn't find relevant to my use case).

Here's my app info:

- Two types of user profiles (Basic & Professional)
- Basic user is an instance of [`User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) with an addition field (`phone`)
- Basic user posts questions (needs help with stuff)
- Pro users provid various services (help/answer the questions posted by basic users)
- Pro users belongs to an `Organisation` class, basic users don't.
- Also, Pro represents its own org, so an `Organisation` belongs to one profile (hence `OneToOneField`)

**Question:** So I need help with deciding whether to create two separate profiles (`BasicProfile` & `ProProfile`) for each type or create a single `Profile` and use a boolean field that says whether a profile `is_pro`or not (much like the django's `is_superuser` boolean field)

Approach 1:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=50)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(ProProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(_('Phone'), max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract  = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

class UserProfile(Profile):
    pass


class ProProfile(Profile):
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Verified'))
```

Approach 2:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=50)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def basic(self, **kwargs):
        return self.filter(is_pro=False, **kwargs)

    def pro(self, **kwargs):
        return self.filter(is_pro=True, **kwargs)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(_('Phone'), max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Verified'))
    is_pro = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = ProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

Currently, these profiles don't have much features (fields), but in future it might get some extra fields.

Which approach would you personally prefer that's more readable, extendable/maintainable if more fields/features are added to user profiles?

Some use cases:

`p = company.profile` (Approach 2)

`p = company.proprofile` (Appr 1)

`if company.profile.is_pro: # (Appr 2)
    do_something()`

Creating the profile instance when a user is registered, then:

```
p = ProProfile.objects.create(user=self.user, phone=phone)
org = form.cleaned_data['org']
Organisation.objects.create(name=org, profile=p) <-- This is simplified version, I do extra validation before creating org)
```

Furthermore, each profile type has its own version of Dashboard. When `Pro` login he/she see more stuff, list of tasks posted by basic users, org details, leads etc.

EDIT: Also, with Approach 1, getting the profile from `request.user` will be a hit and miss case, e.g.

```
try:
    request.user.proprofile
    # it's Pro
except RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:
    # it's basic
    pass
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if I where you I would do the following:

## In case a basic user can't become in a pro user:

#### in the models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# create a custom user model
class User(AbstractUser):
    # declare basic user attributes        

    def is_professional(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'pro_user')

    def get_profile(self):
        if self.is_professional():
            return self.pro_user
        return self

# create a pro user model
class ProUser(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL):
    # declare pro user attributes
```

then register yor user model in the **settings.py** as the default authentication user model:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.User'
```

**Each user kind must have a different registration.

then when you get an user, call user.get_profile() will give you the user instance with all attributes ("basics" or "pro + basics") depending the case.

## In case a basic user can become in a pro user:

#### in the models.py

```
# create a custom user model
class User(AbstractUser):
    # declare basic user attributes        

    def is_professional(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'pro_profile')

# create only one profile for pro users
class ProUserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="pro_profile"
    )
    # declare pro user attributes
```

then register yor user model in the **settings.py** as the default authentication user model:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.User'
```

in this way you only have one user profile, and all users will have the basic attributes.